# Decomposing representations of SU(2) into irreducible representations.

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory

Let $N\in SU(2)$, $D^{(\frac{1}{2})}$ denote the fundamental representation of $SU(2)$ (i.e $D^{(\frac{1}{2})}(N)=N$ ) and let $\psi_{\alpha}\in\mathbb{C}^2$. Then $\psi_{\alpha}$ transforms under this irrep by $\psi_{\alpha}\rightarrow \psi'_{\alpha}=N_{\alpha}^{~\beta}\psi_\beta$ (summation convention in use). In general the $D^{(\frac{n}{2})}$ irrep acts on the space of totally symmetric spinors $\psi_{\alpha_1\dots\alpha_n}=\psi_{(\alpha_1\dots\alpha_n)}.$ I am trying to prove the well known result that $$D^{(\frac{n}{2})}\otimes D^{(\frac{m}{2})}=\sum_{i=|m-n|}^{m+n}\oplus D^{(\frac{i}{2})}.$$

I can do it for the low $m$ and $n$ cases by explicitly decomposing the vectorspace into invariant subspaces according to the above decomposition (and showing that they are indeed invariant). But how might I go about proving the result in general? I have read that you can do it using homogeneous polynomials and characters, but I would prefer it if I could do it by finding a general decomposition into invariant subspaces. Please do not post the answer, I only want suggestions, thank you.

Comment: Each of your summands is generated by a highest-weight vector. Why not just write down the conditions for the vector to be highest-weight.

Comment: Some call the result *Clebsch-Gordan formula*. Physicists (ÍIRC) are often more obsessed with the basis elements of those invariant subspaces (where Clebsch-Gordan coefficients appear). Anyway, as more of an algebra guy I would prove this result using formal characters (i.e. dimensions of weight spaces, or eigenspaces of $L_z$). A viable alternative could be to split that tensor product into eigenspaces of a Casimir operator (say $L^2$).

Comment: (cont'd)  All of $L_x,L_y,L_z$ commute with $L^2$, so the eigenspaces of the latter are necessarily then invariant. And in this case those eigenspaces happen to be irreducible. Adding up the dimensions then tells us that we have exhausted all of the tensor product.

Comment: Too bad you are aversive to characters... They are simple Chebyshev polynomials in this case, and the answer is [more or less straightforward](https://www.academia.edu/27311094/Spin_Multiplicities).

Comment: Thank you all for your suggestions (and for the paper Cosmas). I feel like the result becomes kind of obvious once you realise that, in the spinor formalism,  the only invariant tensor is the spinor metric ($\varepsilon_{\alpha\beta}$) and so the only possible decomposition moves down in steps of 1 (not 1/2) from the maximum representation. At the same time your only option is to take traces of the spinor belonging to the lefthand side vectorspace, and this can only be done $m-n$ times (assuming $m>n$), so this is where the decomposition must stop.

Comment: Actually, in [Wigner's classic summary](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-662-02781-3_42), it is a breathtaking *one liner* (31a).